# How do I play audio through my computer to my LG HBS750 (win 7)

Tags: laptop, audio, bluetooth

I have a Dell Inspiron running Win 7 and a LGHSB750 bluetooth headset. I added the headset no problem however the headset never says connected. It does report connected  when paired to my phone but the laptop says it is paired. Any ideas what is the issue and how to fix it so I can use my headset instead of the plug in type?

Answer (score 1):

I know this a really old topic, but hopefully this will help someone in the future..

As the above answer states, first turn off the Bluetooth function on your phone (or any other device your headset may be connected to).

After you pair the headset with your PC/Laptop, right-click on the speaker icon on your taskbar, then click "playback devices".

Right-click anywhere within the list of devices and make sure that "show disconnected devices" and "show disabled devices" are both 'checked'.

If the headset paired correctly, you will now see it in the list of playback devices (Mine actually shows up as 2 separate devices. One shows as "Headset" and the other "Headphones". For listening to normal audio, we want the "Headphones" device.)

Right-click on it ("headphones LG HBS750..") and click "connect" (make sure headset is powered on first!). This may take a few seconds..

After it's connected, right-click one last time and select "Set as Default Device". Make sure your computer and headphone volumes are turned up and hopefully, you are good to go!

Good luck, I hope this answer helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Yes .. the same happened to me .
So the solution is to turn your b. tooth off in your mobile , then try to re-connect your headset to your PC , then you can connect it to your mobile again , this way you can connect the headset to your PC + connect 2 devices at the same time .